# fetch data from table

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have the following table in my database

```
CREATE TABLE `sms_pool` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `ag_id` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `sms_to` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    `template_name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `contents` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    `bulk_flag` VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    `file_name` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `send_flag` VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    `creation_date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `created_by` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `modification_date` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `modified_by` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `processing_msg` VARCHAR(2000) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),

);
```

I wish to write a procedure/function which takes 'id' as input.

If 'id' is present in the table then it should return the corresponding row,

**if 'id' = NULL then it should return all of the rows from the database.**

**NOTE** : if 'id' is not present in table then it should return all of the rows.

How should I do this? Any help is appreciated.
Thank you in advance. :D

Comment: Second situation simply cannot happen because you have declared id as not null.

Comment: `select * from any_table where id = :id or (:id is null)`? Procedure/function may simple open this cursor and return ref to it.

Comment: @e4c5 please note that if 'id' is not present in table then it should return all of the rows.

Comment: @Aleksej mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mean

```
select * from sms_pool
where :id = id OR :id is null;
```

Comment: This does not return all rows when :id is not null but :id is not in sms_pool. You'll need `OR :id is not in (select id from sms_pool)` or similar to achieve that.